Struggling to understand the Householder Arnoldi Algorithm
I have spent almost three frustrating weeks trying to understand the Householder GMRES algorithm. I understand the basic GMRES algorithm the maths of Householder transformations used in QR decomposition, but I am not sure whether this is the same process used in the Householder Arnoldi? What I find most confusing is that Householder transformation process used in QR factorization obtains the next Householder vector from the product of the previous Householder matrices and the input matrix, however the Householder Arnoldi process is based on the product of a Householder matrix and a vector.
A worked example would help clear things up but I cannot find any.
